# Find command not working with -mtime and -daystart parameter in linux-bash

Tags: shell, unix, find, gnu-findutils

I am trying to find the files which are created 10 mins ago and with the `-daystart` parameter (i.e created/modified more than 10 mins but less than daystart) in `find` command, but `-mmin` is taking the priority and `-daystart` is ignored. Any suggestions and comments to fix this issue is appreciated.

Below output shows `-daystart` is being ignored and ideally only the `test` file should be listed:

```
[rshetty@xxx ~]$ date 
Thu Feb 23 12:06:14 CST 2017 
[rshetty@xxx ~]$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -daystart -mmin +10 -exec ls -lrt {} \; 
-rw-r--r--. 1 rshetty users 18 Jan 11 2015 ./.bash_logout 
-rw-r--r--. 1 rshetty users 0 Feb 23 11:50 ./test 
-rw-r--r--. 1 rshetty users 231 Jan 11 2015 ./.bashrc 
-rw-r--r--. 1 rshetty users 193 Jan 11 2015 ./.bash_profile
```

Comment: Are you sure that `-daystart` is what you need? Try setting a time range with anoter `-mmin` or `-mtime` parameter, like `-mmin +10 -mtime -1`.

Comment: @Murphy This is a pretty cool suggestion. Thanks! I am still wondering why it is not working with daystart.

Comment: (Aside: Not really a bash question; you'd have precisely the same behavior starting find from ash/dash/ksh/zsh/fish, or running it with no shell at all (ie. `subprocess.Popen(['find', '.', '-maxdepth', '1', '-type', '-f', '-daystart', '-mmin', '+10', '-exec', 'ls', '-lrt', '{}', ';'])`).

Comment: ...another aside: `-exec ls -lrt {} \;` means you're running `ls` once for every file found, which means it can't do any sorting (`-t` doesn't do anything if it's given only one file!)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's correct I have same problem with other shell too. By the way I am not bothered about  -exec ls -lrt {} \; part because sorting is not my requirement - but thank you for mentioning it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-daystart` modifies the meaning of `-mtime`, `-mmin` and related predicates that operate based on time relative (by default) to the present; it isn't a predicate in and of itself, so unless you use one of these other operations, it has no effect on your `find` command's results.

Thus, if you want to filter mtime relative to the start of the current day, that needs to be specified, as in `-mtime -1`, *after* `-daystart` (whereas your filters relative to the current time should be *before* `-daystart`):

```
find . -type f -mmin +10 -daystart -mtime -1 -exec ls -lrt {} +
```

Note that we're specifying `-mmin +10` *before* `-daystart` to make that relative to the current time, but specifying `-mtime -1` *after* `-daystart` to make that relative to the start of the day.

Note the `+` instead of the `;` -- `ls -t` has no meaning if you only pass one filename per instance of `ls`, since sorting a list of size one will always come back with that exact same list. See [BashFAQ #3](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) for discussion of more robust and reliable ways to sort a list of files returned from GNU `find` by time.

Comment: If I use -mtime -1,  find will list the files from last for 24hrs, but I need it from the daystart.

Comment: That's what `-mtime -1` does when you **don't** also specify `-daystart`. Using `-daystart` changes the meaning of subsequent instances of `-mtime` (and the `-{a,c,m}{min,time}` predicates in general)..

Comment: BTW, if the goal of `-mmin +10` is to avoid operating on files that are still being written, there are better ways to do that -- for instance, if you had a incron job you could immediately trigger an operation on *any* file as soon as (but not before!) the process that's creating or modifying it closes its handle.

Comment: @RanjanShetty, ...I've made some improvements to this answer that hopefully make its applicability more clear.

Comment: Your answers suffix my requirement. Thanks a lot. The need of -mmin +10 is not to filter the files that are current being written, there is a different requirement at my work.

Answer (score 2):

Since you need files which were modified in the last 10 minutes or **less**, you need to pass `-10` to `-mtime` argument, not `+10`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -daystart -mmin -10 -exec ls -lrt {} \;
```

See this page:

- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am looking for files created/modified more than 10 mins but less than daystart.